# MongoDB Mongoose Object attribute is undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, undefined

I am trying to fetch mongodb data using mongoose in nodejs. but finding some strange behavior. when printing the object it is displaying all the attributes. but when trying to print the attribute one by one it is showing as undefined.

Following is the code and output

**Code**

```
// Get cart details
const cart   = await Cart.findById(cartId)            
console.log( " Cart "+JSON.stringify(cart))
console.log( " ID "+cart._id)
console.log( " STATUS "+cart.status)
console.log( " Cart Products "+cart.products)
```

**Output**

```
 Cart {"_id":"5f3d55d4bb24ef4a447169e9","status":"NEW","cretionTime":"2020-08-19T16:39:46.427Z","lastUpdationTime":null,"userId":"5f3a509ebdd13421e8e15ba9","products":[{"unit":"10","_id":"5f3d55d4bb24ef4a447169e8","product":"5f3c0fbd9726ad52248f78ab"},{"unit":"5","_id":"5f3d55eebb24ef4a447169eb","product":"5f3bffaa3a534c04d09f1832"}],"__v":1}
 ID 5f3d55d4bb24ef4a447169e9
 STATUS undefined
 Cart Products undefined
```

Comment: This is pretty strange. Just out of curiosity, what happens when you run `console.log(cart.status)`?

Comment: According to [mongoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), `findById` returns a `Query` object. Maybe you need to see how to extract properties from this query. Some people use `.exec()` directly after `findById()` and then await on this.

Comment: Sorry guys .. my mistake, i forgot to mention all attribute in mongoose model. my bad ..